# Crazy but minor issue in grid-based game

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pygame

This has been really bugging me. I'm creating a game where a hero moves on a grid and part of it involves a collision check. The collision check stops the hero from moving in a direction if something already occupies the grid there.

It works for all directions except down. I can't see why?! It's the same structure for up, down, left and right. They all work, except down. I don't see it, can someone help?

Here is the code:

```
import random as random
import pygame as pygame

pygame.init()  
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode([650, 650])  
Done = False
MapSize = 25

TileWidth = 20
TileHeight = 20
TileMargin = 4

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)



class MapTile(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, Column, Row):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Column = Column
        self.Row = Row


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, HP, Column, Row):
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = HP
        self.Column = Column
        self.Row = Row

    def Move(self, Direction):

        if Direction == "UP":
            if self.Row > 0:
                if self.CollisionCheck("UP") == False:
                   self.Row -= 1

        if Direction == "LEFT":
            if self.Column > 0:
                if self.CollisionCheck("LEFT") == False:
                    self.Column -= 1

        if Direction == "RIGHT":
            if self.Column < MapSize-1:
                if self.CollisionCheck("RIGHT") == False:
                         self.Column += 1

        if Direction == "DOWN":
            if self.Row < MapSize-1:
                if self.CollisionCheck("DOWN") == False:
                    self.Row += 1

        Map.update()

    def CollisionCheck(self, Direction):
        if Direction == "UP":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column][(self.Row)-1]) > 1:
                return True
        if Direction == "LEFT":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column-1][(self.Row)]) > 1:
                return True
        if Direction == "RIGHT":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column+1][(self.Row)]) > 1:
                return True
        if Direction == "DOWN":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column][self.Row+1]) > 1:
                return True

        else:
            return False

    def Location(self):
        print("Coordinates: " + str(self.Column) + ", " + str(self.Row))




class Map(object):
    global MapSize

    Grid = []

    for Row in range(MapSize):  # Creating grid
        Grid.append([])
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            Grid[Row].append([])

    for Row in range(MapSize):     #Filling grid with grass
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            TempTile = MapTile("Grass", Column, Row)
            Grid[Column][Row].append(TempTile)

    for Row in range(MapSize):     #Rocks
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            TempTile = MapTile("Rock", Column, Row)
            if Row == 1:
                Grid[Column][Row].append(TempTile)

    for i in range(10):       #Random trees
        RandomRow = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
        RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
        TempTile = MapTile("Tree", RandomColumn, RandomRow)
        Grid[RandomColumn][RandomRow].append(TempTile)

    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
    Hero = Character("Hero", 10, RandomColumn, RandomRow)

    def update(self):        
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            for Row in range(MapSize):
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[Column][Row])):
                    if Map.Grid[Column][Row][i].Column != Column:
                        Map.Grid[Column][Row].remove(Map.Grid[Column][Row][i])
                    elif Map.Grid[Column][Row][i].Name == "Hero":
                        Map.Grid[Column][Row].remove(Map.Grid[Column][Row][i])



        Map.Grid[int(Map.Hero.Column)][int(Map.Hero.Row)].append(Map.Hero)

Map = Map()

while not Done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            Done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            Column = Pos[0] // (TileWidth + TileMargin)
            Row = Pos[1] // (TileHeight + TileMargin)
            print(str(Row) + ", " + str(Column))

            for i in range(len(Map.Grid[Column][Row])):
                print(str(Map.Grid[Column][Row][i].Name))

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Map.Hero.Move("LEFT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Map.Hero.Move("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Map.Hero.Move("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                Map.Hero.Move("DOWN")

    Screen.fill(BLACK)

    for Row in range(MapSize):  # Drawing grid
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[Column][Row])):
                Color = WHITE
                if len(Map.Grid[Column][Row]) == 2:
                    Color = RED
                if Map.Grid[Column][Row][i].Name == "Hero":
                    Color = GREEN


            pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TileMargin + TileWidth) * Column + TileMargin,
                                             (TileMargin + TileHeight) * Row + TileMargin,
                                             TileWidth,
                                             TileHeight])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()
    Map.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It just makes no sense! 

Doing Map.Hero.CollisionCheck("UP"), Map.Hero.CollisionCheck("LEFT"), and Map.Hero.CollisionCheck("RIGHT") all return True or False, yet Map.Hero.CollisionCheck("DOWN") returns nothing at all?!

Comment: I have never been so confused and frustrated at a piece of code before

Comment: Use `elif`s in your `CollisionCheck` function

Comment: Doing that makes it so that the hero doesn't move at all for me?

Comment: The `Down` isn't quite the same.  Since you have a bunch of `if`s, the `else` goes only with the `Down`.  Since it *is* `Down`, the function doesn't execute the `else`, and it just doesn't return anything, which means it returns `None`.  To fix it, remove the `else:` and put the `return False` at the same indentation as all of the `if`s.  Another way would be to switch from `if ... == False:` to `if not ...:` everywhere.  Incidentally, there are a lot of things here that could be improved.  Once you get it working, I would love to review it over on [codereview.se].

Comment: It wouldn't move at all because you don't want to treat `return False` as a separate case.  You want it to return `False` regardless of which direction it is.  The only qualifier is, has it returned `True` yet?  You don't actually need a check for that because it will already have left the function if it has returned `True`.  Therefore, just take the `return False` outside of the `else`.

Comment: Well explained! It works now, thanks a bunch. I will post it to Code Review and see what kind of feedback I can get there now that it works.

Comment: Don't know how relevant this is, but I managed to get the code you posted in your question titled _How to make an object move through an array of objects on keypress?_ working. Since you deleted the question, I can't post an answer. However you can download the code from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/how-to-make-an-object-move-through-an-array-of-objects-on-keypress.py) if you're still interested.

Comment: martineau, you rock! I really like the way you rewrote certain things, and the code overall appears much easier to read. Thank you so much, I am honestly surprised that you put the time into it and I am very grateful for it. I will continue work now: the next step is to introduce animals that roam around.

Comment: Also, I undeleted the question if you'd like to post your code as the answer.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: It's posted now.  I'm not at my best on it, but I'll blame that on late nights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the `CollisionCheck()` method for the `if Direction == "DOWN":` case is that whenever the `len(Map.Grid[self.Column][self.Row+1])` is less than 2, the method returns `None` *not* the `False` value `Move()` explicitly checks for, so the `self.Row += 1` statement is never executed.

This is because the `else:`, `return False` at the end of the method is only executed when a corresponding length test failed ***or*** `Direction` wasn't equal to any of the direction string values.

The simplest fix is to change all but the first `if` into `elif`'s and remove the `else:` clause at the end:

```
    def CollisionCheck(self, Direction):
        if Direction == "UP":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column][(self.Row)-1]) > 1:
                return True
        elif Direction == "LEFT":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column-1][(self.Row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif Direction == "RIGHT":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column+1][(self.Row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif Direction == "DOWN":
            if len(Map.Grid[self.Column][self.Row+1]) > 1:
                return True

        return False
```

Alternatively, it could be written a little more succinctly like this:

```
    def CollisionCheck(self, Direction):
        column, row = self.Column, self.Row
        if Direction == "UP":
            objects = Map.Grid[column][row-1]
        elif Direction == "LEFT":
            objects = Map.Grid[column-1][row]
        elif Direction == "RIGHT":
            objects = Map.Grid[column+1][row]
        elif Direction == "DOWN":
            objects = Map.Grid[column][row+1]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown direction in CollisionCheck")

        return len(objects) > 1  # adjacent position has more than just grass?
```

BTW, you don't need the `global MapSize` in the `class Map` definition nor that call to `Map.update()` at the end of the `while not Done:` loop (because `Move()` does it).

Comment: Hi martineau, I thought I had! My bad. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An `else` block goes with an `if` and optionally any number of `elif` blocks.  Since you used only `if` blocks, the `else` is really with only the `Down` option.  Let's say you hit down.  Your `if ... == "DOWN":` block will be entered.  If the inner `if` block succeeds, your method returns True.  If it doesn't, the method moves on.  It gets to the `else` block, but it skips it.  Why?  Because we know that the `if` succeeded.  The `else` happens only when the `if` does not succeed.  That means that the `else` happens only when the user types something other than down, so why the `else`? When do you want the method to return False?  You want it return False only if it hasn't yet returned True.  If it has already returned True, it won't get to this point anyway.  Therefore, just use `return False` instead of putting it in an `else` block.